# Is there pythonic oneliner to iterate over lines of a file?

Tags: python, file

90% of the time when I read file, it ends  up like this:

```
with open('file.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        my_function(line)
```

This seems to be a very common scenario, so I thought of a shorter way, but is this safe? I mean will the file be closed correctly or do you see any other problems with this approach? :

```
for line in open('file.txt'):
    my_function(line)
```

Edit: Thanks Eric, this seems to be best solution. Hopefully I don't turn this into discussion with this, but what do you think of this approach for the case when we want to use line in several operations (not just as argument for my_function):

```
def line_generator(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        for line in f:
            yield line
```

and then using:

```
for line in line_generator('groceries.txt'):
    print line
    grocery_list += [line]
```

Does this function have disadvantages over iterate_over_file?

Comment: `is it safe` <- under ideal circumstances, yes. But deployed software is rarely in an ideal environment, and you'll very quickly need to wrap your code in a try/catch. That's where this context manager comes in and makes your life so much easier

Comment: If there is e.g. an encoding error in one of the lines and you exit without closing and disposing the file handle, that can lead to serious problems on file systems if you run into a big number of still held file handles.

Comment: ok, It's clear that no code is safe. But In this context I'm wondering more about "is it less safe than using `with`" or does it have disadvantages over it. Or do you mean that using `with` will take care of the problems you mentioned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building upon the [approach by Eric](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42417226/1639625), you could also make it a bit more generic by just writing a function that uses `with` to `open` the file and then just returns the file. This, however:

```
def with_open(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        return f  # won't work!
```

does not work, as the file `f` will already be closed by `with` when returned by the function. Instead, you can make it a generator function, and `yield` the individual lines:

```
def with_open(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        for line in f:
            yield line
```

or shorter, with newer versions of Python:

```
def with_open(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        yield from f
```

And use it like this:

```
for line in with_open("test.txt"):
    print line
```

or this:

```
nums = [int(n) for n in with_open("test.txt")]
```

Comment: interestingly I edited question to ask about same approach you posted at the same time :) I didn't know about newer versions, thanks.

Answer (score 5):

If you need this often, you could always define :

```
def iterate_over_file(filename, func):
    with open(filename) as f:
        for line in f:
            func(line)


def my_function(line):
    print line,
```

Your pythonic one-liner is now :

```
iterate_over_file('file.txt', my_function)
```

Answer (score 2):

using a context manager is the best way, and that pretty much bars the way to your one-liner solution. If you naively want to create a one-liner you get:

```
with open('file.txt') as f:  for line in f:   my_function(line)   # wrong code!!
```

which is invalid syntax.

So if you *badly* want a one-liner you could do

```
with open('file.txt') as f:  [my_function(line) for line in f]
```

but that's bad practice since you're creating a list comprehension only for the side effect (you don't care about the return of `my_function`).

Another approach would be

```
with open('file.txt') as f:  collections.deque((my_function(line) for line in f), maxlen=0)
```

so no list comprehension is created, and you force consumption of the iterator using a itertools recipe (0-size deque: no memory allocated either)

**Conclusion**:

to reach the "pythonic/one-liner" goal, we sacrificed readability.

Sometimes the best approach doesn't hold in one line, period.